# Identifying top recurring words from a list of e-mails based on a dictionary of interesting words

Tags: python, regex, bash, parallel-processing, grep

A directory D contains a few thousand e-mails in the .eml format. Some e-mails are plain text, others come from Outlook, others have an ASCII header and HTML/MIME content and so on. There exists a dictionary file F containing a list of interesting words (i.e. red\nblue\ngreen\n...) to look for in the files underneath the D directory. The D directory has a large number of subfolders but no files other than the above-mentioned .eml files. A list of top recurring words should be made with these specifications:

- For every interesting word, information should be provided concerning how many times it occurs and where it does. If it occurs multiple times within a file, it should be reported multiple times for that file. Reporting occurrence means reporting a tuple (L,P) of integers, where L is the line number from the top of the e-mail source and P is the position, within that line ,of the start of the occurrence.

This would build both an index to refer to the different occurrences and a summary of the most frequently occurring interesting words.

The output should be on a single output file and the format is not strictly defined, provided the information above is included: interesting words, number of times each interesting word occurs and where it does -> file/line/start-position.

This is not a homework exercise but actual text analysis I would like to make of a fairly large dataset. The challenge I am having is that of choosing the right tool for filtering efficiently. An iterative approach, Cartesian product of words/emails/etc, is too slow and it would be desirable to combine multiple word filtering for each line of each file.

I have experimented building a regex of alternatives from the list of interesting words, w1|w2|w3|..., compiling that and running it through each line of each e-mail but it's still slow, especially when I need to check multiple occurrences within a single line.

Example:

E-mail E has a line containing the text:

^ ... blah ... red apples ... blue blueberries ... red, white and blue flag.$\n

the regex correctly reports red(2) and blue(2) but it's slow when using the real, very large dictionary of interesting words.

Another approach I have tried is:

use a Sqlite database to dump tokens to as they are parsed, including (column,position) information for each entry, and just querying the output at the end. Batch inserts help a lot, with the appropriate in-memory buffer, but increase complexity.

I have not experimented with data parallelisation yet as I am not sure tokens/parsing are the right thing to do in the first place. Maybe a tree of letters would be more suitable?

I am interested in solutions in, in order of preference:

- Bash/GNU CLI tools (esp. something parallelisable through GNU 'parallel'for CLI-only execution)
- Python (NLP?)
- C/C++

No Perl as I don't understand it, unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest breaking down the problem into smaller subsections. In other words, if your problem is parsing .eml files, you should talk about that and nothing else. If your problem is about word frequency, we're willing to assume that you already have (parsed) the data and you just need to analyze it.

Comment: Please assume that extracting text from a variety of source formats (Outlook, plain text with headers, MIME) has already been solved as I am using a library to do that.

Comment: Curious as to why you are worried about the performance as much since you're just outputting to a file......unless you are doing this multiple times every seconds/minutes/hours. If it was once per day, etc, would seem that performance wouldn't be that much of an issue.

Comment: Because I have to pay for it, it's a cloud batch process.

Comment: Can you restate the problem into a couple of paragraphs and some example code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can create/find an eml-to-text converter. Then this is fairly close to what you want:

```
find -type f | parallel --tag 'eml-to-text {} | grep -o -n -b -f /tmp/list_of_interesting_words'
```

The output is not formatted 100% how you want it:

filename \t line no : byte no (from start of file) : word

If you have many interesting words the '-f' in `grep` is slow to start up, so if you can create an unpacked version of your maildir you can make parallel start `grep` fewer times:

```
find . -type f | parallel 'eml-to-text {} >/tmp/unpacked/{#}'
find /tmp/unpacked -type f | parallel -X grep -H -o -n -b -f /tmp/list_of_interesting_words
```

Since the time complexity of `grep -f` is worse than linear, you may want to chop up /tmp/list_of_interesting_words into smaller blocks:

```
cat /tmp/list_of_interesting_words | parallel --pipe --block 10k --files > /tmp/blocks_of_words
```

And then process the blocks and the files in parallel:

```
find /tmp/unpacked -type f | parallel -j1 -I ,, parallel --arg-file-sep // -X grep -H -o -n -b -f ,, {} // - :::: /tmp/blocks_of_words
```

This output is formatted like:

filename : line no : byte no (from start of file) : word

To have it grouped by `word` instead of filename pipe the result through sort:

```
... | sort -k4 -t: > index.by.word
```

To count the frequency:

```
... | sort -k4 -t: | tee index.by.word | awk 'FS=":" {print $4}' | uniq -c
```

The good news is that this should be rather fast, and I doubt you will be able to achieve the same speed using Python.

Edit:

grep -F is way faster at starting, and you will want -w for grep (so the word 'gram' does not match 'diagrams'); this will also avoid the temporary files and is probably reasonably fast:

```
find . -type f | parallel --tag 'eml-to-text {} | grep -F -w -o -n -b -f /tmp/list_of_interesting_words' | sort -k3 -t: | tee index.by.word | awk 'FS=":" {print $3}' | uniq -c
```

Comment: Awesome. I had to study this quite a bit before understanding it, many options I had never used before. It does not solve my problem completely but I learned so much from it that I am going to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

- We don't wish to do something along the lines of "for all emails, perform a regex search and do_something();". I can imagine the length of most emails to be shorter than the list of interesting words so I'd try to process each email individually and extract the necesary information.
- Build a specialized string data structure (such as a [string trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [ternary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree)) to quickly lookup whether a word is interesting or not. I'd have good experiences with building a ternary search tree of words as it allows quick lookups of words.
- The algorithm would then look like this:

(in pseudocode of course)

```
result <- empty list
for each email e:
    for each word w:
        if is_interesting_word(w, string_data_structure):
            add (filename, line_number, start_position, word) to results
```

- The problem is now quite suitable for parallelize with techniques such as [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) (e.g., [Hadoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop)). Each email can be processed independently of the others and no information needs to be shared: the string data structure can be computed prior to processing the emails. In the map step, you extract the necessary information from an email and in the reduce step, you merge the computed values from each email into a single output file.

I would reduce the amount of processing that you need: no regex, no advanced parsing; just walk over each character/line in an email and keep track of where you are (line number, position, et cetera). As a final step, profile your code and optimize where it hurts :)

Comment: I got introduced to "Trie"s by Stanford's Zelenski in her recorded CS106B course, that's what I was hinting to when I mentioned considering using a "letter tree". (CS106B, Stanford, Zelenski, year 2007, minute 20 onwards of lecture 25). I am also familiar with MapReduce and thought like you there would be no issue with fanning out widely parallelisation on data. What about the actual micro-task of finding out if a given word is in the "interesting" set? Hashing? I am really wondering about this...

Comment: The task of finding whether a word is interesting is done with the string data structure. Once you have built the string data structure with all the interesting words, there are known algorithms to check whether a word is in the data structure. You don't hash the words, you implement the algorithm for that particular data structure which returns true or false depending on whether the word is in there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
list = ['a', 'bunch', 'of', 'interesting', 'words']
linepos = 0

with open("file") as f:
    for line in f:
        linepos += 1
        wordpos = 0
        for word in line.split():
            wordpos += 1
            if word in list:
                print "%s found at line %s, word %s" % (word, linepos, wordpos)
```

Comment: I suspect this would be slower than a compiled regex that sifts through each line... A couple of comments: 1) your counters could be simplified by using "enumerate()"? 2) pos needs to be "exact character position" 3) split() is only rough (i.e. watch out for punctuation...)